# C#: Can this code be simplified?

Tags: c#, .net

It feels like this code could be simplified, its really a struggle to write all of this. I'm new to C# and I don't exactly know what it is or what it equals as a previous developer has left it.

Could somebody explain what this is, and how I can maybe simplify it?

```
Convert.ToInt32(new decimal(new int[] {10, 0, 0, 0})
```

Comment: I think he's converting the array of int to a decimal format and then back to int. This, from just looking and not having my computer, is used to parse a 4 byte input to a single integer... The only time I've seen something similar used is when communicating bytes via serial.

Comment: What is the context of the code? Whether we can simplify it or not depends entirely on its motivation. `var x = 10` is certainly simpler.

Comment: If the code you posted is exactly what you're dealing with you can replace it with `10`.

Comment: var myInt = 10 ? maybe

Comment: There is no meaning of doing this operation. I mean conversion.

Comment: So I could just use the value 10?

Comment: If the decimal representation is always this array {10, 0, 0, 0}. Then you can simplify it the whole thing with `10` (as Int32).

Comment: I just copied and pasted this into VS and ran it and it indeed comes out to just be an int with a value of 10.  Is there more to this code (I noticed the parenthesis didn't match up) and if not, did this particular developer have issues with job security?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1de0ya1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should have a read through the following

[Int32 Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents a **32-bit** signed integer.

[decimal (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal)

> The decimal keyword indicates a **128-bit** data type. Compared to other
> floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a
> smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary
> calculations. The approximate range and precision for the decimal type
> are shown in the following table.

[Decimal Constructor (Int32[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1de0ya1(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Initializes a new instance of Decimal to a decimal value represented
> in binary and contained in a specified array.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The binary representation of a Decimal number consists of a 1-bit
> sign, a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the
> integer number and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction.
> The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent
> ranging from 0 to 28.
>
> - bits is a four-element long array of 32-bit signed integers.
> - bits [0], bits [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx), and bits [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) contain the low, middle, and high 32 bits of the 96-bit integer number.

So lets break down what you are doing

```
array = new int[] {10, 0, 0, 0}
```

The array constructor allows you to build a decimal, a *128 Bit* value, out of 3  *32 bit* values and some flags. This actually gets quite in depth, however as far as int is concerned, the first element in the array represents the first *32  Bits* of a decimal value.

**For example**

```
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(new int[] {1, 0, 0, 0}) );
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(new int[] {10, 0, 0, 0}) );
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(new int[] {100, 0, 0, 0}) );
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(new int[] {-1, 0, 0, 0}) );
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(new int[] {-10, 0, 0, 0}) );
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(new int[] {-100, 0, 0, 0}) );
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(new int[] {int.MaxValue, 0, 0, 0}) );     
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(new int[] {-int.MaxValue, 0, 0, 0}) );
```

**Output**

```
1
10
100
4294967295
4294967286
4294967196
2147483647
2147483649
```

But what just happened here! Not even *Integers* will convert the way you think. You would have to consider them as unsigned then convert them to signed.

**I.e**

```
Console.WriteLine((int)Convert.ToUInt32(new decimal(new int[] {1, 0, 0, 0})));
Console.WriteLine((int)Convert.ToUInt32(new decimal(new int[] {10, 0, 0, 0}) ));
Console.WriteLine((int)Convert.ToUInt32(new decimal(new int[] {100, 0, 0, 0}) ));
Console.WriteLine((int)Convert.ToUInt32(new decimal(new int[] {-1, 0, 0, 0}) ));
Console.WriteLine((int)Convert.ToUInt32(new decimal(new int[] {-10, 0, 0, 0}) ));
Console.WriteLine((int)Convert.ToUInt32(new decimal(new int[] {-100, 0, 0, 0}) ));
Console.WriteLine((int)Convert.ToUInt32(new decimal(new int[] {int.MaxValue, 0, 0, 0}) ));      
Console.WriteLine((int)Convert.ToUInt32(new decimal(new int[] {-int.MaxValue, 0, 0, 0}) ));
```

**Output**

```
1
10
100
-1
-10
-100
2147483647
-2147483647
```

Though really, here is the clincher, you are building a *128 Bit* decimal (by bits), yet you want to squeeze it back in to a signed *32 Bit* value, i.e `Int32`...

The biggest value you can hope to get is that of a *32 Bit* Number, period.

So this whats the points of the decimal here? Not Much (all those other Bits are worthless, and in fact will probably get you in to more trouble.

My gut feeling is you just want to create an `int`... If you want an `int` (*32 Bit* number), why not just create one to start with...

```
int = 1;
int = -1;
int = int.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting way to represent `int` value of `10`. This looks like part of some bit operation code. If you look at the constructor for `Decimal` it has explanation as to what this code is doing.

`Decimal` has a constructor which takes an array of `int`s. The first three numbers represent the lower, middle and upper bits of 96 bits of `Decimal`. The fourth element in the array is a sign bit with scaling factor.

I think this is what it is doing internally. Creating a binary representing first 3 bits and then converting it to decimal.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] input = new int[] {10, 0 , 0, 0} ;


        string b1 = Convert.ToString(input[0], 2).PadLeft(32, '0');
        string b2 = Convert.ToString(input[1], 2).PadLeft(32, '0');
        string b3 = Convert.ToString(input[2], 2).PadLeft(32, '0');

        decimal result = 0;

        string s = b3+b2+b1;

        Console.WriteLine("Binary : "+s);

        for( int i=0; i<s.Length; i++ ) 
        {
          // we start with the least significant digit, and work our way to the left
          if( s[s.Length-i-1] == '0' ) continue;
          result += (decimal)Math.Pow( 2, i );
           Console.WriteLine(result);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Calculated " + result );
        Console.WriteLine("By Framework " + (new decimal(input)));


    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NDcUvU

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1de0ya1(v=vs.110).aspx